Is there ancient Egyptian literature surviving today?
In short: is there anything like the Gilgamesh epic surviving from Ancient Egypt? Similarly old and similarly secular?
The Wikipedia article talks at length about who would write and what they were writing about in Ancient Egypt, and gives an impression, nothing of the Gilgamesh scale was even written -- much less survived to be mentioned by the later historians.
Is that really true?

How many equivalents to the Gilgamesh epic exist from that period in other cultures? Perhaps we're just lucky that Gilgamesh's tale lasted as it did.

I'm not judging the Egyptians :) I just want to get my hands on something comparably old as Gilgamesh to read.

Similarly to @SteveBird's point, but from another angle: How close to the EoG does it have to be? Does it need to be an Epic story with a non-deiety culture hero? Or is anything that isn't an accounting ledger or king list or king bio carved on a monument good enough?

Yes, @T.E.D., that's the criteria. Deities can be present, but the text should not be religious overall. So the story of Osiris is not it, for example, but some kind of Egyptian Ramayana would've been it

There are plenty in the article you cited. Check especially this paragraph.

Thanks, @cmw, the paragraph does, indeed, mention such things having been written -- and you can make your comment into an answer for me to accept. Maybe, you can expand it a bit by listing, what has survived to our days. All I see on Amazon, for example, are modern retellings of the Egyptian myths, not the actual verbatim translations...

Middle Kingdom literature is rife with lengthy narrative stories about mortals. The best example is perhaps the Tale of the Shipwrecked Sailor, but there are numerous stories in full or in some fragmentary state.
The article you linked has a bunch listed:

The genre of "tales and stories" is probably the least represented genre from surviving literature of the Middle Kingdom and Middle Egyptian.[95] In Late Egyptian literature, "tales and stories" comprise the majority of surviving literary works dated from the Ramesside Period of the New Kingdom into the Late Period.[96] Major narrative works from the Middle Kingdom include the Tale of the Court of King Cheops, King Neferkare and General Sasenet, The Eloquent Peasant, Story of Sinuhe, and Tale of the Shipwrecked Sailor.[97] The New Kingdom corpus of tales includes the Quarrel of Apepi and Seqenenre, The Taking of Joppa, Tale of the Doomed Prince, Tale of Two Brothers, and the Report of Wenamun.[98] Stories from the 1st millennium BC written in Demotic include the story of the Famine Stela (set in the Old Kingdom, although written during the Ptolemaic dynasty) and short story cycles of the Ptolemaic and Roman periods that transform well-known historical figures such as Khaemweset (Nineteenth Dynasty) and Inaros (First Persian Period) into fictional, legendary heroes.[99] This is contrasted with many stories written in Late Egyptian, whose authors frequently chose divinities as protagonists and mythological places as settings.[51]

All of these works survive, a few complete and some in a fragmentary state. There are several collections of Egyptian literature that contains these stories, including a three-volume-in-one volume by Miriam Lichtheim. Two other well-respected anthologies are compiled by John Foster (Ancient Egyptian Literature: An Anthology, 2001) and Simpson & Ritner (The Literature of Ancient Egypt: An Anthology of Stories, Instructions, Stelae, Autobiographies, and Poetry, 3rd ed. 2003).

One piece of this literature was even rewritten as a novel in the modern times (M. Waltari,  Egyptian) and there is a movie based on it, Sinuhe, the Egyptian, freely available on youtube.
